# liferay 6 How to get the Folder id of a folder

Tags: liferay, document-library

Having a folder name e.g. "images", how can i get the folderId attribute of this folder? I need the folderId so i can then use the DLFolderLocalServiceUtil interface and methods to query for the files in the dir

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Long parentFolderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID; // if the id of the parent is set to default
DLFolder dir = DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(groupId, parentFolderId, dirName);
```

see: [DLFolderLocalServiceUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.html#getFolder(long,%20long,%20java.lang.String))

Where `groupId` is the id of the site the request is coming from, you can get it using `themeDisplay`:

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = 
     (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
long groupId = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId();
```

and `parentFolderId` is the id of the folder containg the folder you're searching for and it is set when you add a new folder using:

```
    DLFolder newFolder=addFolder(long userId, long groupId, long repositoryId, boolean mountPoint, long parentFolderId, String name,
 String description, boolean hidden, ServiceContext serviceContext)
```

Comment: Could you please describe `groupId` and `parentFolderId` as well? Code only answers are harder to understand.